# recommended, like a priggish elder sister, to unruly siblings and apprentices

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm not sure if I'm misreading the part in bold. Is it saying that "Jane Austen, who was recommended to"? Is *recommended* a reduced relative clause here?

Jane Austen was an early favorite of male critics, **recommended,
like a priggish elder sister, to** unruly siblings and apprentices. G. H. Lewes recommended Austen to Charlotte Bronte in 1848, but Bronte rejected her as being elegantand confined, "a carefully fenced, highly cultivated
garden, with neat borders and delicate flowers."
[*Source*](https://www.encyclopedia.com/social-sciences/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/womens-literature-19th-century-british-women-writers)

Comment: Yes; purists might say that 'who were ...' (the nearest NP being 'male critics') is strictly deducible, but this of course doesn't construe. The sentence remains garden-pathy though and is awkward. Worse, there is something of a disjoint between the statements 'Jane Austen was an early favorite of male critics'  and 'Jane Austen was recommended, like a priggish elder sister, to unruly siblings and apprentices'. I'd want a semicolon at least.  I suspect the crit is itself dated. It's rather overblown.

Answer (score 1):

It means she was 'recommended' as a role-model to 'unruly' boys and girls; presumably like Charlotte Bronte was as a young girl, given the quote.

The reference to 'sublings' is to suggest a family context.

And the 'priggishness' is a pejorative word for polite and orderly.

(Personally speaking, I'd quite like to have Jane Austen as an elder sister - and maybe Charlotte Bronte as a younger one ..!)